# Can I use Win32.TaskScheduler to schedule my procedures?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I want to use http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

I can schedule external Actions with it alike in example.

Can I schedule my internal actions with it or maybe I should use something else for external tasks?

e.g. :

```
    public static void cstask() {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService()) {
            const string taskName = "Test2";

            System.Action test = new System.Action( () => {
                ;
                }
            );

            Task t = ts.AddTask(taskName,
               new TimeTrigger() { StartBoundary = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(1), Enabled = false },
               //new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", "C:\\")
               (Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Action)test

               );

            ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask(taskName);
            }
        }
```

->

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Action' to 'Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Action'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invoke a System.Action directly with the windows task scheduler.

But you can create a scheduled task that executes your application. The needed information to invoke an internal action could be passed by through commandline arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a job for `Reactive Extensions`

```
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

and

```
IDisposable subscription = 
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
        .Take(1)
        .Subscribe(i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something delayed by an hour");
});
```

dispose the subscription to kill it before it runs. If you want your
task to return something for processing then a little different.

```
double SomeFunction(){ 
    ...
}
```

and

```
public async double DoItInOneHour(){
    return await Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
            .Take(1)
            .Select( i=> SomeFunction());
}
```

will asynchronously wait for the timeout, evaluate SomeFunction and then return
the result to value.

Comment: Ahh but RX is not persistent like the TaskScheduler you are referring to. So this is probably not what you are looking for.